# Getting range error when trying to store block.line to String using firebase ml vision in flutter and dart

Tags: firebase, algorithm, flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

I'm progressing to learn to create a simple OCR application with help of online references, but currently when I try to store each line of the text into a String array and try to print it, I get  Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index).

UPDATE: I tried to print only the first line and it seems to be null.

What I try to do is that I have a piece of paper with 2 lines of texts like:

> FIRST
>
> SECOND

I've tried to store them into String first, String second by using this:

```
for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {
  first = block.lines[0].text;
  //second = block.lines[1].text;
  }
}

if (this.mounted) {
  setState(() {
    //firstOCR and secondOCR were declared as String
    firstOCR = first;
    //secondOCR = second;
  });
}
```

The container used to output the OCR data:

```
Container( height: 60,
           child: SingleChildScrollView(
           child: Text(firstOCR /*+ secondOCR*/,),
                  ),
                ),
```

I wish to know what is the reason causing the error here, what is the proper approach if I want to store each line as a String variable?

Console error

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
> The following assertion was thrown building DetailScreen(dirty, state: _DetailScreenState#714b4):
> A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:378:10)
> #3      _DetailScreenState.build (package:kindergarten_ams/screens/ocr_detail.dart:163:32)
> #4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:27)
> #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4567:15)
> #6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4739:11)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you point out at which line the error occurs?

Comment: Ah sorry, I've tried to print only one line (first line) and edited my question with error details.

Comment: Haven't worked with firebase, but there seems to be a missing argument here after the comma - `child: Text(firstOCR /*+ secondOCR*/,)`